# MonacaでApplication Loaderを用いて申請時に ERROR ITMS-90020: "This bundle is invalid. It does not contain a .app bundle, which must be a readable directory."

Tags: monaca

Monacaでハイブリッドアプリを開発、いったん申請が通った（約１か月前）のですが、却下されたのでバージョンアップした上で、Application Loader 3.0でビルドしようとしていますが、下記ERROR ITMS-90020というのが出てアップロードできません。
何が原因でしょうか。

```
ERROR ITMS-90020: "This bundle is invalid. It does not contain a .app bundle, which must be a readable directory."
```

というメッセージが表示され、アップロードできない状態です。

Answer (score 1):

単純ミスです。解決しました。
Monaca　iOSビルド・リリースビルド後、ダウンロードしたフォルダ全体を圧縮し、zip化して、Application Loader　で「Appデリバリ」かけていました。

ダウンロードしたフォルダの中を開いて「MonacaApp.app」（実際には拡張子が消えている事も...）を圧縮し、「MonacaApp.zip」を「Appデリバリ」かけてやる登録できました。